# How to access a session variable in view ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Once a user logs in I want to keep his details in the session and access these in ejs templates. How do i achieve this ?

```
app.post('/registration', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.session.user_name = req.body.user_name;
    res.render('pages/registration-data');
});
```

I want to access req.session.user_name from all the .ejs templates I have if that is initialized/and/or present in the session. Is it the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.locals` object to store user/session details inside session, avaliable from any template

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

```
app.post('/registration', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.session.user_name || req.body.user_name;
    res.locals.user_name = name;
    res.render('pages/registration-data');
});
```

Comment: I tried this already. But then also its coming in registration-data.ejs.it's not being displayed in rest of the pages.

Comment: You must place this expression in firts authenticate middleware and call next()